# Hide Worksheet Based on Dropdown Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide/unhide a worksheet based on the dropdown selection in cell `B12`. I've tried many different variations of code, and cannot get it to work. Here's what I have right now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B12") = "No" Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Visible = False
Else
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you put this code? In the sheet code module?

Comment: Not enough data about context.

Comment: You should probably just use ```Target``` instead of ```ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B12")```

Comment: @BigBen Thanks!! That was the issue... was putting in on wrong worksheet module...

Comment: Thanks @BigBen @Warcupine. Changed to `If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then`